# Knife sharpening - can it be done anywhere?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

Can you take a Challa knife to any knife sharpener or would you have to Kasher it after it is sharpened? Would there be a difference if it is a meat or cheese knife?

Comment: Are you asking about a sharpener that has been used for non-kosher knives or perhaps one that wasn't toiveled? I'm not clear what the question is.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1848. (A _chala_ knife is serrated, typically.)

Comment: @msh210, While it is certainly very common for decorative "challah knifes" to be serrated, there is a practice to sharpen one's challah knife on erev Shabbos mentioned in Orach Chaim and there is a custom not to use a serrated challah knife.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu, I never knew that! Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109545/759

Comment: This question seems to be revolving around not understanding the physical process of knife sharpening. If using stones (wet stones), the process is essentially cold and the various stones wear down. They also get resurfaced in routine maintenance. Belt sharpeners (a modern innovation) are also a composite of grinding material that wears down in the sharpening process. Generally, heat is to be avoided because it will ruin the tempering of the blade. Serrated knives use a different process (a honing rod) with diameter appropriate for the serration. Rekashering the blade is not relevant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rabbi Forst's "The Laws of Kashrus" references a Mordechai cited at the end of Beis Yosef 122 which permits using a single knife sharpener for meat and dairy, though he does note that they must be clean and that some have the custom of using different sharpeners (page 354).

I was unable to locate the precise reference inside the Beis Yosef, but the context seems like it is *probably* speaking about using a non-Jews knife sharpener.

Indeed the Star-K  [specifically allows](http://star-k.org/cons-faqs-KKMU.htm#knives) using a knife sharpener that is used for non-Kosher knifes providing that the knife is clean. Both the Star-K and the [CRC Article on Knife Sharpening](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/knife_sharpening.php) speak of the issue of the heat generated by electric sharpeners used by sharpening services and both conclude that the heat is generally not sufficient to effect a transfer of taste (this would seem to implicitly support my gut feeling that even though with respect to knives the pressure can effect a transfer of taste even without heat, that characteristic of knives isn't relevant here). They both note that one must be able to ensure that the knife they are getting back is their own.

Comment: כתב עוד שם דטעמא דסתם כלים של נכרים אינן ב"י משום דהוי ס"ס ולפ"ז כשמוליכין הסכינים להשחיז בבית האומן ומחזירן לבו ביום ליכא האי טעמא דספק ספיקא משום דבו ביום החזירן א"כ אם נשתמשו בהם היינו בו ביום בודאי וליכא למימר ספק משום דלא נשתמש בו כלל דודאי רגיל להשתמש בו כיון שאין ישראל עומד ע"ג הלכך צריך הגעלה

Comment: This is the bet yosef