# Can you use a not kosher knife sharpening stone/wheel

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, kashering-kosherization, slaughter-shochet-shecht

I learned the the sharpening stone kashers the knife

But are there any sources regarding the use of a sharpening stone/wheel that was used for non kosher knifes (possibly used even when dirty knives) for sharpening kosher knives?

Can use the same sharpening wheel to sharpen meat and milk knives?

Comment: Possible duplicate  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13462/759

Comment: @DoubleAA yes possible (very sorry)