# Does a knife sharpener need to be considered kosher or kashered?

Tags: kashering-kosherization, utensil

Does a knife sharpener need to be kosher?

Would I need separate sharpeners for milchig and fleishig knives?

Does it to be treated like any other kitchen utensil and need kashering?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13462/knife-sharpening-can-it-be-done-anywhere?r=SearchResults

Comment: @GershonGold Duplicate?

Comment: It's not the same question, the question in link is exactly the issue of the mordechai and it's depends if the non Jew sharpener gives it back at the same day. Here the question is about influence of the grindstone for the cashrut

Answer (score 1):

BY YD 122

> כתב עוד שם דטעמא דסתם כלים של נכרים אינן ב"י משום דהוי ס"ס ולפ"ז כשמוליכין הסכינים להשחיז בבית האומן ומחזירן לבו ביום ליכא האי טעמא דספק ספיקא משום דבו ביום החזירן א"כ אם נשתמשו בהם היינו בו ביום בודאי וליכא למימר ספק משום דלא נשתמש בו כלל דודאי רגיל להשתמש בו כיון שאין ישראל עומד ע"ג הלכך צריך הגעלה

At first glance:

The only problem is if you have a doubt if the sharpener used the knife for non kosher food. But the action of sharpening with the the same grindstone for dairy and meat knifes is not a problem